# Unknown version of Tomcat was specified. tomcat 8.5 linux

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, installation

Here is my problem

[image]

Eclipse only recognizes my version 7 of tomcat ...

However it remains a mistake ... it does not find the jre. Ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you've already do that but if you get this issue, it means you certainely make wrong in one of these steps. So let me describe steps:

1. Go to tomcat site's download page for version 8: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi
2. Download the desired version (in this case, 8.5.15) for linux so the tar.gz in the Core sub-part. Manually or with curl (before that, move in the folder you want to download the compressed package):

   `cd /tmp` *(for example)*

   `curl -O http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.15/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.15.tar.gz`
3. Verify integrity of the downloaded tar.gz with MD5 or SHA1 (optional but it sometimes reserves a few surprises)
4. Uncompress the package where you want so:`cd /usr/local` and `tar zxvf apache-tomcat-8.5.15.tar.gz`
5. Make sure the JAVA_HOME variable is correctly defined because Tomcat needs it to work
6. Add a new server runtime so: Windows>Preferences>Server>Runtime Environment
   Then, add button. Select "Apache Tomcat v8.5" on the list. Next, then browse to select the correct directory /usr/local/* . Actually, you need to choose the directory which directly contains bin, conf, lib and so on.

And it will work fine

Let me know if you fix the problem or if it persists.

Comment: The problem was the variable JAVA_HOME, everything works for TOMCAT version 7 but not for version 8 and 9 which always returns me "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified"

So I will use version 7 thanks for your contibution!